# What is the meaning of Arakawa Under the Bridge's opening theme song?

Tags: music, arakawa-under-the-bridge

I'm kinda wondering what the opening theme song of Arakawa Under the Bridge, ***Venus and Jesus*** lyrics mean.

On the third stanza,

> *A neighbor of Venus
>
>   Why? During that interval that we don't know
>
>   Jesus lives across the hall
>
>   I'm hearing something bad*

It mentions the name, *Jesus*. What does that stanza imply? Does it have something to do with the Christian religion?

> *A neighbor of Venus*

Maybe, Earth?

> *Why? During that interval that we don't know*

Interval we don't know? Maybe, before the concept of time existed?

There are also other lines that I don't quite understand.

Lyrics taken from [**Lyrics Translate**](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/venus-jesus-venus-and-jesus.html).

Comment: Looking at the Japanese lyric, I guess the translation doesn't make any sense because it tries to translate line by line, while the stanza should be translated as a whole. I think the lyrics more or less means: "Jesus has started living across Venus, during the time she is not aware, and that's quite a situation she got into", if we translate it as the view of a 3rd party. As for the choice of Venus and Jesus, I guess they rhyme and Venus = girl while Jesus = boy? From the view point of someone who hasn't watched the series, it looks like a bad choice, since it is not related to the reference.

Comment: It's a standalone song that was used for the OP. Isn't there an official translation or something?

Comment: @nhahtdh I guess they used Venus because Nino, the MC girl, says she's from Venus. But I don't know about the use of Jesus. And if so, Jesus pertains to Kou?

Comment: @KousakaKirino well, lets face it Kou does see himself rather highly, its not out of the question for him to compare himself to Jesus. So Nino claims to be a Venusian, Kou would probably see himself as Jesus. It does fit.

Comment: @Daboyzuk Hmm, you have a point.

Answer (score 3):

In an English fan dub of the OP [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDy0pvuxTKo), they use "Jesus" as a curse word, but I haven't found anything on Japanese people doing that, so I would assume they could not decipher the meaning and just went with what sounded good.
Jesus is also mentioned in the title so it seems to refer to a person.

Another thing to think about is the "I'm in hell again" line. Is that meant to tie in?
Well, the Japanese word used "地獄"　can refer to either the Buddhist hell or the Christian one. (Used in Mark 9:43-44.)
It doesn't seem to refer specifically to the Christian hell.
As the full word was "生き地獄", I think a more accurate translation may be "hell on earth".

It may just be another instance of "use Christian themes to sound cool" thing. Random Christian stuff like crosses and such are added in to Japanese media a lot because it is exotic and strange to them. Using "Jesus" in a song is an example of that I have seen before.

As *Arakawa Under the Bridge* is very random, it's hard to tell. The perspective of the song appears to change between the stanza and the person who translated it is actually French, and from what I can gather, some bits may not be entirely accurate. However, the French version seems to take some liberties that are not in the Japanese for some reason. I also looked at [this translation](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/arakawa/venusandjesus.htm) which varies slightly.

Basically: The song is random like the series, and the use of "Jesus" is just to make it sound cool.

Coincidentally, Hikaru Nakamura, the mangaka of *Arakawa Under the Bridge* also writes another great series called *Saint☆Oniisan*, which is a slice-of-life about Jesus and the Buddha on holiday living in an apartment in Tokyo. Probably nothing to do with it, but it's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The music says Venus as a reference to woman, specifically the girl of the anime. The time people don’t know is how we say about the time before been born, but in this case, I think it’s before they got to know each other, that’s why is WE used there.
Jesus I think is like the creator of everything, and in the anime you also have that Christian guy living in Arakawa, it might be just a reference to the character or even when saying Jesus is across the hall could be like we don’t see him but He’s close and the event of the couple meeting was a divine intervention.
And then hearing something bad, if you pay attention, the singer is looking it all from outside, it’s not part of the whole scene, so probably the singer has bad feelings about the future, maybe because many times during the anime you can never be sure if everything is going to be fine.
That’s how I see the lyrics, too many years I’ve watched the anime and sorry to reply now, but I am in a bench in Arakawa and found your question when searched about the op songs.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but whatever. I think this song is actually a masterpiece that represents Nino's feelings along with some of Recruits. There are lyrics but what is most notable to me is how the OP expresses their journey together and how it sounds a lot like possibly the inner thoughts of nino wondering if she should be more honest